# changing intents within the same activity Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to edit player on the same layout as creating a player.

When i press the edit player button , I change the headings of the create player page to "Edit Player" and populate the listbox with the player name. I would like to know how i can return to the create player activity when i press done. Thankyou

Comment: if its possible just use two separate activities.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would call `finish()` to finish the current activity, and the user should be redirected to the first activity on the stack, which apparently should be the Create Player activity.

So, set a click listener for the `done` button, an in `onClick` call `finish()`

Or, you may start the Create Player activity in `onClick`, like in you would start any regular activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EditPlayer.this, CreatePlayer.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: is it possible to refresh CreatePlayer activity?

Comment: Yes. You should finish it, and start it again.

Comment: What i did was, when you press the finish edit button, i just reloaded the createPlayer activity.. Its all solved now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> When i press the edit player button , I change the headings of the
>   create player page to "Edit Player" and populate the listbox with the
>   player name.

Seems like you did all actions in one activity?

Better to create two activity if you want to switching.  creating a player A activity -> edit pressed -> startActivity B -> editing -> done and finish() activity B -> resume A activity.